# Visual Basic element

Tags: vb.net, textselection

I'm kind of new at visual basic. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to make this single element. a single line combo box with two scroll bars. For instance if I had the numbers 1-4 loaded into it, it would start displaying 1, I hit the down arrow it displays two etc, but if I hit the up arrow it goes down an index. I can make the combo box to only have one arrow, but I need the rest of the scroll bar. I tried a list box but can't do it where it displays one item at a time. Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right track with a list box. Just resize it so that it only displays one item at a time. (Not that I can imagine why you'd *want* such a control. Be kind to your users!)

Comment: Well I'm making a sudoku Puzzle, it's hard to explain without being able to post a SS of exactly what I'm looking for. like it contains the numbers 1-4. if i hit down it goes to 2, if I hit up it goes back to one

Answer (score 1):

I think you could you use NumericUpDown component. 
You could set the increment on properties sectian and it has two arrows up and down.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the NumericUpDown control.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for a numeric control. You can set a min and max value and so on. For numeric options is the way to go.